# Not able to view complete design on an Android Device

Tags: android, android-layout

What is actually happening that I have created a design to view my page. But I think there is some issues because of that my complete design is not showed on the device. This is complete XML file .

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_bg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_demo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tripTypeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roundtripTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/round_trip_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OneWayTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/oneway_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multicityTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/multicity_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fromToLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tripTypeLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fromLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fromTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="From" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:background="@layout/shape_line" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/departLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/twoway" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/to" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:background="@layout/shape_line" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/arrivalLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dateLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fromToLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/departdateLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/deparDateTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/departdate" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/departDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="dd/mm/yyyy" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/returndateLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/returndata"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/returndate" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/returnDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="dd/mm/yyyy" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/travellers_data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Travellers" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/travellers_data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/adults"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Adult"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="12 + Years" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/adult" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Children"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="2 - 11 Years" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/children" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Infant"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Below 2 Years" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/infant" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/class_pref"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/travellers_data"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Class"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@layout/shape_rectangle"
                android:text="Economy" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pref Airline"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@layout/shape_rectangle"
                android:text="All  " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/class_pref"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/searchflight" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to view my searchflight image on the bottom of my device

Comment: Try `<View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />`. I have tried. Do change width as per your requirement. And don't forget to put below your view where you want a gray line.

Comment: i have tried the same chintan see that layout whose id id traveller data in that after adult description i want to create a horizontal line same in case of child  and infant

Comment: i have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717093/create-a-horizontal-line-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `ScrollView` with your layout. Though your layout is very long, `ScrollView` will provide space to render views.

Just put `ScrollView` before `RelativeLayout`. Means your `RelativeLayout` will be only child of `ScrollView`.

**Note**

`ScrollView` holds only 1 child.

**Edit**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- Your Other views inside -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what changes i have to if i wish that my layout look perfect in horizontal as well as  vertical

Comment: `ScrollView` will provide vertical scrolling. `HorizontalScrollView` is other then this. :(

Comment: @chitan when i am using this app in horizontal view in the device it looks perfect but when i am using this holding my device vertically it doesn't look perfect

Comment: @Rahul, Then you should go for two different layout my friend. If your landscape layout is somewhat different then vertical one, `layout-land` will be your other layout. :)

Comment: as of now i fixed up the orientation in the manifest file.So that means i have to create two different layout for horizontal as well as vertical

Comment: Yes. If **those are different** then and then only. Otherwise one layout will be sufficient for both.

Comment: like i have posted my complete layout in the question from this can u let me know what i have to from the code u will get the idea

Comment: Its typical for me to arrange those views my friend. But I see both layout one by one. Landscape has more space and its perfectly fit on screen. But in vertical due to width, it collapse each other. So you should create another layout which has vertically views set instead of horizontally.

Comment: @chitan i need one more help if u can see in the travellers section the position of 2 ,1,0 in not in a line .can please suggest what i have to do that for

Comment: is it possible to arrange them top to bottom?

Comment: how we can put a horizontal line between the Adult,Child and Infant

Comment: create a `View`. Make height of **1dp**, set background color as per your requirement or set image.

Comment: i have tried that but i am not getting my solution in between of adults ,children and infants i need a grey horizontal line

Comment: help me on this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716183/error-occuring-unable-to-instantiate-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code in u r activity.java file before setcontentview

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```