# Create a Vertical Line in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a vertical line .

I used this code to create a vertical line.

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="1dp" 
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

This my complete layout please suggest where i have do the changes:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/travellers_data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travellerText" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/adultsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/adults"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/adultText"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/adultAgeLimit" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/adult" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/childrenText"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/childrenAgeLimit" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/children" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/noOfChild"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/infantAgeLimit"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/infantAgeLimit" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/infant" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/noOfInfants"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What doesnt work? Do you want to know where to put the line?

Comment: i am confused where to put this what changes i have to do in my xml please the image for u r refrence

Comment: Placing the `View` right before the last closing `</LinearLayout>` should do it.

Comment: @SiddharthLele please the image for the reference and suggest me where i have do the changes

Comment: @Rahul: I just did buddy. Why don't you try placing it there and see how it works out? No harm doing that eh? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 <View
     android:layout_width="1dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/travellers_data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/travellerText" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/adultsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/adults"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/adultText"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/adultAgeLimit" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/adult" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/childrenText"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/childrenAgeLimit" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/children" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/noOfChild"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/infantAgeLimit"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/infantAgeLimit" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/infant" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/noOfInfants"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don´t think that´s going to be a _horizontal_ line - I think he wants the line at the bottom of his image

Comment: @Rahul, I couldn't understand where actually you stuck. And SO will lock commenting also if we do chat in comments. That is why I stop posting comments. And where I am working, chat is banned . :(

Comment: He clearly asked for a horizontal line: "I am trying to create a Horizontal line ." - Might not be what he meant though - @Rahul: please edit your question if you meant _vertical_

Comment: @ChintanRathod can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805672/design-progress-dailog-android